# Suggest elements of an object array which is not there in another object array

Tags: javascript, jquery, arrays, json, performance

I have two array of objects.

```
Array1 : [{"id":20,"stName":"ABC","className":"A"},{"id":30,"stName":"ABD","className":"B"},{"id":40,"stName":"ABE","className":"C"},{"id":50,"stName":"ABF","className":"D"}]
Array2 : [{"id":110,"stName":"ASA","className":"X"},{"id":120,"stName":"ASB","className":"Y"},{"id":130,"stName":"ASC","className":"A"},{"id":140,"stName":"ASD","className":"C"},{"id":150,"stName":"ASE","className":"Z"}]
```

Here

> array1 have classNames as A, B, C, and D.
>
> array2 have classNames as X, Y, A, C, and Z

A function should return the `classNames` of `array2` such a way that the `classNames` does not belong to `array1`

> The return from the function will be an array which contains X, Y, and Z as elements.

How to write this function in `javascript` with less time complexity, because array1 and array2 may have more than 20 objects.

**Edit**

This is the script which I used using `for loop`

```
array1 = [{"id":20,"stName":"ABC","className":"A"},{"id":30,"stName":"ABD","className":"B"},{"id":40,"stName":"ABE","className":"C"},{"id":50,"stName":"ABF","className":"D"}]
array2 = [{"id":110,"stName":"ASA","className":"X"},{"id":120,"stName":"ASB","className":"Y"},{"id":130,"stName":"ASC","className":"A"},{"id":140,"stName":"ASD","className":"C"},{"id":150,"stName":"ASE","className":"Z"}]

function findSuggest(){
    var sug = [];
    for(array2_count=0;array2_count < array2.length;array2_count++){
        for(array1_count=0;array1_count < array1.length;array1_count++){
            if(array2[array2_count].className == array1[array1_count].className){
                break;  
            }
            else{
                if(array1_count == (array1.length - 1)){
                    sug[sug.length] = array2[array2_count].className;

                }
            }   
        }
    }


}
```

Here `sug[]`  will have all suggestions.

Comment: Do you have anything beyond the task description? This sounds like a homework assignment and you want someone to do it for you.

Comment: This is a part of a product am working on, and the data which I provided is just for simplify the question. This snippet a part of an algorithm, which need more efficiency. I already implemented this with normal `for` loop, but want to improve the efficiency of it.

Comment: @lucuma I tried this by iterating to every element and compare its values. It is more time consuming if more number of objects are there in an array.

Comment: @JavadShareef Update your question with the code you've tried that you need help with.

Answer (score 18, accepted):

Here's the general idea of the algorithm:

- Iterate over `Array1`.

  - Add the current item's `className` to a truth map
- Iterate over `Array2`

  - If the current item's `className` is not in the truth map, add it to the result.

That simple, `O(n+m)` (worst case `O(2n)`). By a truth map, my intention is a plain js object, where each key is (in this case) a `className`, and each value is `true`.

Comment: +1 For suggesting an approach vs. giving code. This is definitely the way to go about this, at least until ES6 sets are available.